# Help understanding definition of independence of random variables

Tags: probability

Definition: The random variables $\{X_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ are said to be independent if:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap_{j=1}^{k} X_{i_{j}}\in B_{j}\right)=\prod_{j=1}^{k}\mathbb{P}(X_{i_{j}}\in B_{j}),
\end{equation}
for all $k\geq 2, i_{1}<i_{2}<\dots<i_{k}$, and $B_{1},\dots,B_{k}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$.

**My question**: What is the point of the indices $i_{j}$? Is it because one only considers a finite subset of $\{X_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$? My interpretation of the definition above is as follows:

*The random variables $\{X_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ are said to be independent if:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap_{n\in I} X_{n}\in B_{n}\right)=\prod_{n\in I}\mathbb{P}(X_{n}\in B_{n}),
\end{equation}
for any finite index set $I\subseteq\mathbb{N}$.*

Is my interpretation wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct. While it is true that this definition only considers finite subsets, this restriction is due to $k$ being finite, and not the indices. I believe that the point of the indices $i_j$ is only to ensure that every set of some $X_n$ is counted only once. It is perfectly fine to have the definition of independence not to include the stipulation $i_1 < i_2 < i_3 < \cdots< i_k$ and instead just the stipulation that none of the $i_j$ are equal. Note that if you choose the second condition, then you are overcounting every index set $k!$ times, e.g. the index set $\{1, 2, 3\}$ is counted in all of its six permutations.